# Automatically generate code to dynamically create Java objects (Reflection)

Tags: java, reflection

I have classes which are automatically created from a JSON schema. In my Example one of these classes is called `AvroPropertie`.

Declaring and initializing objects from this class looks like this:

```
AvroPropertie aPropertie = AvroPropertie.newBuilder()
                    .setName(properties.get("name").asText())
                    .setDate(properties.get("date").asText())
                    .build();
```

If the JSON schema differs the variables like `name` and `date` differ as well. There could be more, less or totally different ones. It's always only these setters and the `build()` method at the end.

Is there a way to generate this code automatically? Maybe reflection?

More context: I use the [ApacheAvro Serializing and deserializing with code generation](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/gettingstartedjava.html#Serializing+and+deserializing+with+code+generation).

Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Reflection` you can:

1. Invoke `static` `newBuilder` method to create builder.
2. Find all `fields`/`setters` for given `POJO` class. If in all cases `setters` on builder and `setters` on `POJO` have the same name like in your example it should be easy to convert.
3. Invoke `build` on builder instance to create new `POJO`.

Using basic `Java` `Reflection` and `Stream` `API`-s it could look like below:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReflectionApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("name", "John");
        properties.put("date", "today");

        AvroPropertie manualInstance = AvroPropertie.newBuilder()
                .setName(properties.getProperty("name"))
                .setDate(properties.getProperty("date"))
                .build();

        Object dynamicInstance = AvroAutoCoder.createAndSet(AvroPropertie.class, properties::getProperty);

        System.out.println(manualInstance);
        System.out.println(dynamicInstance);
        System.out.println("manualInstance == dynamicInstance => " + manualInstance.equals(dynamicInstance));
    }
}

class AvroAutoCoder {

    public static Object createAndSet(Class clazz, Function<String, String> dataSupplier) throws Exception {
        Object builderInstance = findMethod(clazz, "newBuilder")
                .invoke(null);

        Class<?> builderClass = builderInstance.getClass();
        getSetters(clazz).forEach(setter -> {
            try {
                String fieldName = setter.getName().substring(3).toLowerCase();
                findMethod(builderClass, setter.getName())
                        .invoke(builderInstance, dataSupplier.apply(fieldName));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        });

        return findMethod(builderClass, "build")
                .invoke(builderInstance);
    }

    private static Method findMethod(Class clazz, String methodName) {
        return Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredMethods())
                .filter(method -> method.getName().equals(methodName))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }

    private static Stream<Method> getSetters(Class clazz) {
        return Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredMethods())
                .filter(method -> method.getParameterCount() == 1 && method.getReturnType() == Void.TYPE)
                .filter(method -> method.getName().startsWith("set"));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
AvroPropertie[name='John', date='today']
AvroPropertie[name='John', date='today']
manualInstance == dynamicInstance => true
```

#### Comment added by the Author of question:

In this specific example class `APropertie` has a static inner class named `Builder` which holds the wanted setters. In this case the `getSetters()` methods needs to be changed a little bit:

```
// Find all setter of class
private static Stream<Method> getSetters2(Class clazz) {
    Optional<Class> first = Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredClasses())
            .findFirst();

    return Arrays.stream(first.get().getDeclaredMethods())
            .filter(method -> method.getName().startsWith("set"));
}
```

Comment: For some reason I get an Exeption: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of  arguments: 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at services.AvroAutoCoder.createAndSet(AvroAutoCoder.java:17)
 at services.ReflectionApp.main(ReflectionApp.java:19)
`
but the .invoke() function should work with null because "newBuilder" is static.

Comment: @Philipp, maybe there is an exception from a rule and `newBuilder` method in this case requires some arguments?

Comment: The problems seems to be, that the `getSetters` method returns null. The required setter are inside an inner class in the `APropertie` class so I think I have to get the inner class first and then get the setters eg. `getName` and `getDate` from that class.

Comment: Ziober btw. this was one of the best answers I ever got in SO. Thanks for taking the time!